# Creating Directory Server

Tags: configuration, directory

I'm trying to create a private Tor network and currently configuring the Directory Server.
I run the command

```
tor --list-fingerprint
```

But it returns

```
Clients don't have long-term identity keys. Exiting.
```

If I correctly understand, I need the fingerprint for this line in torrc config file:

```
DirServer [nickname] [flags] address:port fingerprint
```

Where should I get the fingerprint for the Directory Server ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this all manually, you might want to try out Chutney (https://gitweb.torproject.org/chutney.git/) to set up a private network for you.

To answer your question directly, you need to create a dummy configuration. The following will work:

```
DirServer test 127.0.0.1:1 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
OrPort 1
DataDirectory /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Could you provide further information about how to create this dummy config?